# Why won't my RaisedButton press trigger the plotting function?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart

Here's my map widget:

```
    SizedBox(
      height: 350,
      child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: _myLocation,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
          }),
    ),
```

and here's my _plotCurrent function:

```
 Future<void> _plotCurrent() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {



      print("test");

      PageController _pageController;
      GoogleMapController mapController;
      LatLng center = const LatLng(35.3090281,-73.75914);
//  Location location = new Location();
      Position currentLocation;
      final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

      final marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("curr_loc"),
          position: center,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Your Location'),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker
      );
      setState((){
        _markers.add(marker);
      });

      print("test2");


    }
  }
```

test1 and test2 print just fine when I press this button:

```
    ListTile(
      title: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: _plotCurrent,child: Text("PLOT"), color: Colors.grey,textColor: Colors.black,)),
```

Why won't this plot? nothing happens at all.

I was only able to get points to plot if I set markers: markers as a widget option for my map and it only worked on startup. Here's the code for what worked:

```
  Set<Marker> markers = Set();
  markers.addAll([
    Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('value'),
        position: LatLng(33.2201422, -71.6958883)),
    Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('value2'),
        position: LatLng(33.2930696, -71.641829)),

  ]);
```

^although, that's not what I want. I want to be able to press a button and have those plot. So, do I have to refresh my widget somehow? Or maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: You've defined `_plotCurrent` as an async function. That's y test1 and test2 pass. Try using await, I think for `_markers.add()`, so its `await _markers.add()`

Comment: same thing happened after i deleted the code between prints and used await:         Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

      List<Placemark> p = await Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      Placemark place = p[0];

Comment: Oof. Then I've no idea what's wrong, mate. Do give an update if ya do find the solution.

Comment: @t0m3k where is `_markers` being used in the widget tree?

Comment: @dev-aentgs  it's not. I tried setting markers: markers, in the tree and it actually worked but it has to be able to access markers... when markers is in a button, it can't access it and the program won't compile. I'm new to DART and am having trouble wrapping my head around this. do you know how to have markers: markers, in the tree when it's not yet available due to the button not being pressed?

Comment: @dev-aentgs Maybe I need a "getter" ? with async... so confusing.

Comment: oh. make `_markers` class level variable instead of function level.

Comment: doh!!! augh..  headache.  thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to take credit for the answer, I'll mark you as correct.